# Nginx: connect() to xxx.xxx.xxx.184:3000 failed (22: Invalid argument) while connecting to upstream,

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, node.js

This is my first time asking question on serverfault. If I miss something, please do let me know!

I have been trying to solve this problem for two days now. Still can't find a solution. Here's my scenario:

**Server A**

- Node app A on port 3000
- Nginx on port 80
- when I go to `/hello`, app B should be served from Server B

**Server B**

- Node app B on port 3000

When I visit `/hello`, I get `502 Bad Gateway`.

In my error log, I see this:

```
connect() to 162.243.104.184:3000 failed (22: Invalid argument) while connecting to upstream, client: 75.72.170.8, server: 107.170.64.149, request: "GET /hello/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://162.243.104.184:3000/hello/", host: "107.170.64.149"
```

Here's my nginx conf for Server A:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

  server_name 107.170.64.149;

  location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://107.170.64.149:3000;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

  location /hello {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://162.243.104.184:3000;
    proxy_bind 162.243.104.184;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

In my `/etc/sysctl.conf`, I added:

`net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind=1`

to allow processes to bind to the non-local address because I previously got this error:

```
bind(162.243.104.184) failed (99: Cannot assign requested address) while connecting to upstream, client: 75.72.170.8, server: 107.170.64.149, request: "GET /hello/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://162.243.104.184:3000/hello/", host: "107.170.64.149"
```

Any guidance or help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

***Edit 1***

My new nginx config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        server_name 107.170.39.161;

        location / {
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_pass http://107.170.39.161:3000;
          proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location /hello {
          rewrite /hello(.*) /$1 last;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_pass http://162.243.33.9:3000;
          proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

***Edit 2***

**Server A**

- http://107.170.113.66/
- this server serves appA
- when I go to `/`, I should see `SSR Landing Page` which is served from appA
- when I go to `/hello`, I should supposedly see `hello` which is served from server B. But instead I got `There is no route for the path: /hello` in the browser console and I didn't see any request to server B

**Server B**

- http://107.170.98.207:3000/
- this server serves appB
- when I go to `/hello`, I see the page.

I apologize for changing the server address so often.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to make the outgoing requests to server B originate from `162.243.104.184`? From the information you have provided, I see no need for that, and therefore the `proxy_bind` statement is not needed and actually causes only problems.

`proxy_bind` assigns `162.243.104.184` as the source IP address for the requests to server B, and therefore the server B sends replies back to that IP address, that is, back to itself.

Then, if you want the requests for `/hello` go to `http://162.243.104.184:3000/`, you need add a `rewrite` directive to change the URI:

```
rewrite /hello(.*) /$1 last;
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I actually tried that before. But it seems like server A is not sending request to Server B. You can check out http://107.170.39.161/hello in the browser console. My server B is located here http://162.243.33.9:3000.

Comment: When I visit the `/hello` URI, I get a HTTP 301 redirect to `/hello/` URI. That URI displays a HTML page which contains some JavaScript. It is impossible for me to see where the response really comes from. Only you can see it from your web server logs.

Comment: I just updated my nginx config above. Is there anything wrong? I'm not quite sure what's going on here. Oh man! I'm confused!

Comment: Did you try it yourself and is it working like you expect it to work? The configuration looks fine to me.

Comment: Yeap, I tried it and it's not working like I need it to be. I updated my post, see *Edit 2*. And thank you for being so patient!